# Japa Parser fetch MethodCallExpr inside MethodDeclaration

Tags: java, parsing

Inside `visit(MethodDeclaration n, Object arg)` I want to fetch `MethodCallExpr`.
How should I go about this.
Please help.

```
private static class MethodVistor extends VoidVisitorAdapter {
        @Override
        public void visit(MethodDeclaration n, Object arg){
            System.out.println(n.getName());
            System.out.println(n.getBody().getStmts());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Java Experts,

Please someone revert.

Comment: ** Someone please revert **